# Converting Column in Grid to the Picture

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a way to convert whole Column from Grid to the Image in Windows Phone 7.1 app. I tried to find a way to do that, but cannot find anything.

My problem is that I have to change that:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="180" Source="{Binding ***0}" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Height="30" Width="30" Source="{Binding ***1}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding ***2}" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

into one picture. So I must change whole Grid.Column="0" from the main Grid into the Picture which size is 180x180. After that I must save it into the *.jpg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a bitmap from a UI element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638675%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and then [save it as a jpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

As you have multiple elements (everything in the column) you may have to capture multiple bitmaps, combine them and then save as jpeg.

Comment: I don't think so. I forgot to metion that I have to get in the end a *.jpg file.

Comment: So you want to capture whatever is in column one as an image, resize it and save as a jpeg? Is that right? if so, what have you tried?

Comment: I didn't need to resize it. I just have to put all things from the first column together. I've tried to do something with C# Images, but couldn't find any prepared solutions. Maybe I'll try something with Images Strings..

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's enough for m purposes.